How to extract two types from the Generic type with two parameters in TypeScript?
I have following types:
export interface TypedDocumentNode<R, V> {}

type ClaimResult = {
  id: string;
  status: string;
};

type ClaimInput = {
  code: string;
};

type ResetResult = {
  id: string;
  userId: string;
};

type ResetInput = {
  email: string;
};

type Operations = {
  Claim: TypedDocumentNode<ClaimResult, ClaimInput>;
  Reset: TypedDocumentNode<ResetResult, ResetInput>
};

I am trying to write generic function execute such that it shall take operation name (keyof of operations type) and respective input as variables and then returns the corresponding result. For example:
// Valid possibilities
execute('Reset', { email: 'test@test.io' });
execute('Claim', { code: 'test-unique-code' });

This is my type definition for execute function:
export async function execute<
  Operation extends keyof typeof Operations,
  Document extends Documents[Operation],
  TResult extends Document extends TypedDocumentNode<infer X, any> ? X : never,
  TVariables extends Document extends TypedDocumentNode<TResult, infer V> ? V : never,
> (
  operation: Operation,
  variables?: TVariables
): Promise<TResult> {

  // Rest of the definition.
}

However, the problem is that this definition allows other input types as well:
// Should be invalid combination
execute('Claim', { email: 'test@test.io' });

Is this possible to achieve this in TypeScript?

Please add the missing types to your question e.g. TypedDocumentNode

Is ApiOperation the same as Operation?

You probably should have only a single generic type parameter for that function - the key into the Operations type.

@Bergi, Yes. That was the issue. I should use Operation instead of ApiOperation.

Yes, this can be done using TypeScript's inference capabilities (example). Does that meet your needs? If so, I can write it up as an answer — if not, what did I miss?

@jsejcksn That works!

You can derive type information from the Operations type using TypeScript's inference capabilities.

See Inferring Within Conditional Types in the handbook for more info.

When using conditional inference, things can become more verbose than usual… so creating a couple of generic type aliases will help prevent repetition. The following types use the infer keyword to derive the original type information from the associated generic parameter positions within the Operations type:
// Original type for reference:
type Operations = {
  Claim: TypedDocumentNode<ClaimResult, ClaimInput>;
  Reset: TypedDocumentNode<ResetResult, ResetInput>;
};

type DocumentNodeResult<T extends keyof Operations> =
  Operations[T] extends TypedDocumentNode<infer Result, unknown> ? Result : never;

type DocumentNodeInput<T extends keyof Operations> =
  Operations[T] extends TypedDocumentNode<unknown, infer Input> ? Input : never;

Then you can use them to create the function signature for your execute function:
declare function execute<T extends keyof Operations>(
  operation: T,
  variables: DocumentNodeInput<T>,
): Promise<DocumentNodeResult<T>>;

execute("Reset", { email: "test@test.io" });
/* ^? function execute<"Reset">(
  operation: "Reset",
  variables: ResetInput,
): Promise<ResetResult> */

execute("Claim", { code: "test-unique-code" });
/* ^? function execute<"Claim">(
  operation: "Claim",
  variables: ClaimInput,
): Promise<ClaimResult> */

execute("Claim", { email: "test@test.io" }); /* Expected error:
                   ~~~~~
Object literal may only specify known properties,
and 'email' does not exist in type 'ClaimInput'.(2353) */

Code in the TypeScript Playground

Yes, it's possible.
Your function has to infer the type of operation through a generic variable, then pass that generic into helper type aliases:
// This can be directly implemented in the two types below, but I think it's more organized this way.
type NodeTypesOf<Operation extends keyof Operations> = Operations[Operation] extends TypedDocumentNode<infer Result, infer Input>
 ? { result: Result, input: Input }
 : never;

type InputOf<Operation extends keyof Operations> = NodeTypesOf<Operation>['input'];
type ResultOf<Operation extends keyof Operations> = NodeTypesOf<Operation>['result'];

export async function execute<Operation extends keyof Operations>(
  operation: Operation,
  variables?: InputOf<Operation>
): Promise<ResultOf<Operation>> {
  // Rest of the definition.
}

Playground

Assuming TypedDocumentNode is only used for the sake of type inference,
another way to approach this is to directly map the input and result types in the TypedDocumentNode interface:
interface TypedDocumentNode<R, V> {
    input: V;
    result: R;
}

Now you don't need the helper type aliases and can directly pull the types in your function:
export async function execute<Operation extends keyof Operations>(
  operation: Operation,
  variables?: Operations[Operation]['input']
): Promise<Operations[Operation]['result']> {
  return Promise.resolve(0 as any)
  // Rest of the definition.
}

Playground


Side note: In your examples you wrote Operation extends keyof typeof Operations. Notice that typeof isn't necessary here. It's actually a mistake to put it there. In type-world, typeof pulls the type of a runtime variable into TypeScript. Operations is already in type-world (it's a type alias), hence you can directly call keyof Operations.


This is a much simpler approach; however, I do not have control nor do I know the implementation details of the TypedDcoumentNode interface as it is imported from third-party library. Also, the type Operations doesn't exist in my main code; rather it is a value and thus I used the typeof Operations. Nevertheless, that's for a more clearer explanation and clarity.
